# Separate URL and Data for an excel style =HYPERLINK field

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a csv file which contains a filed which is intended to provide a backing link when inported to Excel. Example content is:

*"=HYPERLINK(""https://app.redflagalert.net/search/company/00975699/"",""CHILTERN HILLS MINERAL WATER LIMITED"")"*

Is there a way, within CsvHelper to separate this into field into the two separate values?

Comment: Why do you need CSVHelper when you can do it without the CSVLibrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should at least give you a good idea of how you could do it.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Company");
            writer.WriteLine("1,\"=HYPERLINK(\"\"https://app.redflagalert.net/search/company/00975699/\"\",\"\"CHILTERN HILLS MINERAL WATER LIMITED\"\")\"");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.CompanyLink).ConvertUsing(row => row[1].Split(',')[0]);
        Map(m => m.Company).ConvertUsing(row => row[1].Split(',')[1]);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyLink { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```